# Will reading an unintialized value more than once always give the same value?

Tags: c, operating-system, malloc, virtual-memory

Let's say I have this very simple piece of code (in this code n = 128, but assume the array size can be anything):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 128);
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that (so please refrain from mentioning this in the comment) the memory block pointed to by `p` is uninitialized and therefore the output of this program can be anything.

My question is the following: For every `n`, is the result of `p[i]` for all `0 <= i < n` consistent?  More specifically, for each read of `p[i]` (in the SAME invocation of the binary), will the result be the same for equivalent `i`?

In other words, will both `printf` statements in a given iteration of the above loop print the same value?

Comment: `p` is not uninitialilsed, it gets cleanly written in the line with the malloc.

Comment: `p` is initialized (but check that `malloc` doesn't return NULL). It's the memory chunk that `p` points to that is uninitialized, and using it is UB.

Comment: Would you like to know about the values read from `p[i]` for same values of `ì`  across several executions of the program? Or is it about the values read in the same run of the program, just several times?

Comment: @Yunnosch I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you asking if `printf(%d\n", p[i]);` followed by `printf(%d\n", p[i]);` with both print the same value?

Comment: @dbush in essence, yes.

Comment: yes, the memory values will stay the same during the SAME invocation of the binary. The data in memory is indeterminate, not magically randomly changing. Once you own that memory, nothing else can legally touch it, and the OS should enforce that. Of course with subsequent invocations of the binary, no such guarantees can be made.

Comment: @user1413793 What functionality  are you trying to get from such code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to do this:

```
  int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 128);
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    printf("%d\n", p[i]);
  }
```

You invoke [undefined behaivor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you read an indeterminate value.  Once you invoke undefined behavior, all bets are off.  The program could crash, it could exhibit strange behavior, or it could appear to work normally.

So the C standard makes no guarantees that both calls to `printf` will print the same value in the above code, even though many implementations probably will.

As to **why** this is undefined behavior is a little tricky.  The bytes returned by `malloc` (as well as locals that are uninitialized) have **indeterminate value**.  This means it could be either an **unspecified value**, which means any value, or a **trap representation**.  Reading a trap representation is what caused undefined behavior.

A trap representation means a bit pattern that does not signify a valid value for a given datatype.  Certain CPUs will trigger a fault if a trap representation is read.

There is however an exception for character types, i.e. `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char`.  These types *cannot* have a trap representation.

From section 6.2.5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Types:

> *15* The three types `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are collectively called the *character types*. The implementation shall
>   define `char` to have the same range, representation, and behavior as
>   either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

From section 6.2.6 regarding Representation of Types:

> Certain object representations need not represent a value of the
>   object type. **If the stored value of an object has such a
>   representation and is read by an lvalue expression *that does not have
>   character type*, the behavior is undefined.** If such a representation is
>   produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object
>   by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the
>   behavior is undefined.50) Such a representation is called a trap
>   representation.

So if you used one of these types as follows:

```
  unsigned char *p = malloc(128);
  for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    printf("%u\n", p[i]);
    printf("%u\n", p[i]);
  }
```

This would **not** be undefined behavior.  The values would simply be *unspecified* instead of *indeterminate*, and both calls to `printf` are guaranteed to print the same value.

Comment: didn't know about trap representations.. interesting

Comment: `unsigned char` does not have traps.  `signed char` may have traps.

Comment: Rarely these days a `signed char` may contain a "trap representation" §6.2.6.2 2  Using just `unsigned char` avoids the trap issues.

Answer (score 1):

**No it will not**. The value of them will be indeterminate. So it may vary in each run. Using them in the code will invoke *undefined behavior*. If it contains some garbage value - it is wrong expectation if you want to get uniformity among them. No they wont be.

You may use `calloc` to have allocated memory initialized with `0`. But `malloc` returns address of memory that is uninitialized. *The value it has is indeterminate*.

From standard: [**§7.22.3.4**](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4p2)

> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and ***whose value is indeterminate***.

#### Edit:

OP asked that the value will always be same in a particular invocation of the binary? (both paragraphs clarify this)

<strike>Suppose there is `100` in uninitialized memory and after some operation still if you didn't assign anything to it - then the value would be same.</strike> It's undefined behavior reading it. (We shouldn't think oustide the scope of the program - in program we would know what it value is - by reading it - and it's UB to read it).

But there is no use - even with that. You can't use it. As using it is undefined behavior.

Now how would you know that they are same? You would think about printing it. But if you print it - then it would be an Undefined behavior. *Reading an uninitialized value is UB.* (The way you do.) The correct way to put is - behavior will not be consistent when it is UB.(chux pointed this).

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: I understand that on mulitple invocations of the binary, the results will be different. But in the same binary, will referencing p[i] give the same result?

Comment: @user1413793.: Yes but there is nothing you can do with that - using that is UB.

Comment: I'm not asking about the usability of it. Merely what the behavior is and if that behavior is consistent.

Comment: Behavior is not specified to be consistent.  It is UB.

Comment: "The answer is - yes. " implies a speicied behavior to somehting that is UB.

Comment: There's the official answer according to spec, and then there's reality. True, reading uninitialized values is officially UB, but I do not know of any C compiler on the planet that will do anything other than simply return the value in memory, which will indeed be consistent because you own it and no one else will write to it. If there were such a compiler, I wouldn't use it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker.: Yes but C has its rules - and it's intricate at some parts. So much scope of misinterpretation of standard.

Comment: @chux.: I have edited it to be more relevant. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks for the earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is the following: For every n, is the result of p[i] for all 0 <= i < n consistent? More specifically, for each read of p[i] (in the SAME invocation of the binary), will the result be the same for equivalent i?

On some systems it will be the same. On others it will not.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @user1413793 There is little to eloborate.  The behavior is undefined.  It might  be the same on every platform you try today.  It might not tomorrow on each and every invoaciton.  The program may even crash,

Comment: "On others it will not" is not really supportable.  Even if we accept for the sake of argument that the behavior is undefined (but see my answer with respect to that), such undefinedness does not support the proposition that there are any systems on which the program would fail to produce pairs of identical numbers.  Undefined is *undefined*, not *random*.

Comment: You presume that the operating system will run the program the same way each time. That is not a valid assumption these days. OS's frequently map applications differently on each run and may initialize data to different values. So it can be random or it could be the same (on a system that runs applications the same each time).

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, will both printf statements in a given iteration of the above loop print the same value?

It is not guaranteed.

Attempting to read an indeterminate value invokes undefined behavior - *any* result is allowed (including a segfault).

On an x86-based system, you will *most likely* see the same value printed both times (assuming it doesn't segfault on the first one).  However, this is not behavior you should expect or rely on - this is a coding error, full stop.

Answer (score -1):

The values you see are just the interpreted binary values from where your array is initialized. It may be the ghost of old data written in the same place.

Comment: I understand that. But on future invocations, will `p[i]` be the same?

Comment: In the same execution, if you don't touch the data it should be the same. However if you run your program again there is no chance the values are the same

Answer (score -1):

An object allocated via `malloc()` has "allocated" storage duration and (initially) indeterminate value ([C2011, 7.22.3.4/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4p2)).  Contrary to some claims here, reading an indeterminate value does not necessarily produce undefined behavior.  Moreover, a value being indeterminate does not mean that it can arbitrarily change while the program is running.  It simply means that the value is

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation

([C2011 3.19.2/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2p1))

The problem is with the possibility of a trap representation.  Specifically:

> Certain object representations need not represent a value of the
>   object type. If the stored value of an object has such a
>   representation and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have
>   character type, the behavior is undefined. If such a representation is
>   produced by a side effect that modifies all or any part of the object
>   by an lvalue expression that does not have character type, the
>   behavior is undefined. Such a representation is called a trap
>   representation.

([C2011, 6.2.6.1/5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p5))

Your code does read indeterminate values via the lvalue expression `p[i]`.  ***If*** any of those values happen to be trap representations, then your program's behavior is undefined.  Otherwise, there is no justification in the standard for the (unspecified) value not being read just fine, and repeatably.

Now here's the thing: in an abstract sense, your program therefore has the potential to exhibit undefined behavior.  If it does exhibit undefined behavior then all bets are off, and in particular, the `int` values in your allocated object might change without warning, or appear to do so.  Thus, C indeed provides no guarantee that your program will print pairs of identical numbers.

On the other hand, few C implementations provide `int` types that afford any trap representations, and yours is unlikely to be one.  If your implementation does not afford any trap representations of type `int` then the indetermination of the value of your allocated object cannot cause the `p[i]` expressions in your program to produce undefined behavior when it runs on that implementation.  On a conforming implementation with that common characteristic, your program *will* print pairs of duplicate values.